# WPF Keystroke Dynamics, best way to measure flight time?

Tags: c#, wpf, keystroke, biometrics

Im making an app for recognising people by key pressing time. Thats how i measure time:

```
    private void Label_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.A || e.Key == Key.O)
        {               
            stopwatch.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void Label_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.A)
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            string aS = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(); //get time of pressing key
            int aI = Convert.ToInt32(aS); //string -> int
            a += aI; //summary of pressing key
            stopwatch.Reset();
            aCounter++;
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.O)
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            string oS = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
            int oI = Convert.ToInt32(oS);
            o += oI;
            stopwatch.Reset();
            oCounter++;
        }
  }
```

And i think i have a problem with a flight time, because sometimes a measure for specific key is ==0. If there is any method to help me with handle flight time properly? Or maybe you have some advice? Thanks for help

Comment: You're could be catching O when A is released and O hasn't been.  Not sure how but the logic in the handler doesn't seem to conform with the logic starting the stop watch.  I believe it should be if A or O then stop and depending on which add.  However, this is still broken somewhat.  Although having a stop watch for every key may be impractical, based on this logic, I feel like you need to.  Possibly hash it out so that you can or monitor up down of keys less independently.

Comment: I thinked about it, so in this case the easiest way to achive that thing is to initialize stopwatch to every key (there would be 7 of them)? I think i need WPF master here, because im new in c# :D

Comment: Add pseudo to the question, at the end, describing exactly what you're trying to achieve step by step, and myself or someone else will most likely answer it based on what you've started.

Comment: I think i know how achive that. I will not start tons of stopwatches, i will get timer from c# and then, when s1 will press key, i will send a time to array and when someone will key up, another time to array. I think then i wont have problem with flight time

Comment: What is the point in converting a value to a string and then converting it back from a string?